# Is there a size limit to the PNG file size for a SilverLight Image?

Tags: silverlight, bitmap, deepzoom

I have been running into issues loading Images into a SilverLight Application.

These images have been generated for DeepZoom purposes and have sizes of over 30 Megs (as PNG).

I have been told there might be a limit to BitMap Sizes that can be loaded, I would like to know where I can have a point of reference to this kind of information so I can decide the next step forward.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](http://www.marklio.com/marklio/CommentView,guid,f5216e74-ce9f-4b7a-b1de-157ea51bf987.aspx) states that the maximum pixel size of the images appears to be around 20516 x 15291 pixels. However, one of the comments states:

> ...I have a prototype that smoothly
>   renders the OpenStreetMap project with
>   a world map size of 67108864 x
>   67108864 pixels.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the problem with inappropriate file format message, try to crop the image for few pixels. It worked for me.